# Polymorphic issue with sqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Got the 'No such polymorphic_identity 0 is defined' error while doing this:

My base class is

```
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=False, index=True) # TODO unique=True
    password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    birthdate = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    type = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    # Inheritance
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',
        'polymorphic_on': 'type',
        # 'with_polymorphic': '*'
    }
```

My derived class is

```
class Patient(User):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    patient_id = Column(String, nullable=False)

    # Inheritance
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'patient',
        'polymorphic_on': 'type',
    }

    # Relationships
    docs = relationship("Document", back_populates="patient")
```

Then I do

```
users = db.query(User)
print(users.statement)
print(f"Count is {users.count()}")
user = users.first()`
```

Creating the hierarchy works fine (both User and Patient tables) but retrieving Users failed. Same error when trying to retrieve Patients.
The SQL query is displayed and seems good. The query is successful, the error arises at the very last line when extracting an actual User object.
Any help. I am beginner with sqlalchemy

Comment: Can you verify the data in the type column of your User table? Ensure that the values correspond to the polymorphic_identity values of your class hierarchy ('user', 'patient', etc.). It seems like there might be entries with a type value of 0, which is not defined in your class hierarchy.

Comment: it is an integer. I tried with an enum and also a string. Populating works fine in all the cases, but loading fails always the same way

Comment: You should either use string type for field 'type' or specify `polymorphic_identity` as numbers (integers) instead of strings 'user' and 'patient'. SQLAlchemy gets the value of column `type` from DB (wich is integer) and compares with the values of `polymorphic_identity` (wich are strings)